# Dividir dataFrame conforme a quantidade de linhas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Gostaria de saber se é possível separar  de uma forma  um data frame de +- 300mil linhas em quantidades pré estabelecidas de linhas e salvar em xlsx como os cabeçalhos cada parte.

Eu pensei em usar o loc, porém teria que usar uma máxima e minimo de linhas, e gostaria de tentar fazer por exemplo, a cada 3 linhas salva o dataframe com as colunas.

Código:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cor': ['azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'preto', 'azul', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'amarelo'],
                   'preco': [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,1]})

df2 = df.preco

df['acumulado'] = df2.cumsum()

df

##################################
Resultado: 
    cor   preco acumulado
0   azul    1   1
1   preto   1   2
2   amarelo 1   3
3   azul    2   5
4   preto   3   8
5   amarelo 4   12
6   preto   5   17
7   azul    3   20
8   amarelo 2   22
9   azul    4   26
10  amarelo 1   27
```

Comment: Você que particionar o arquivo em arquivos menores?

Comment: Isso.  mas numa quantidade móvel que o usuário vai ter que mudar.  por exemplo. a cada 3  x linhas, salvar o arquivo em xlsx.

Comment: ele vai da um `input` e que vai determinar o corte no arquivo?

Comment: o `truncate` não te atende?